# How do I see if the program freed the memory

Tags: visual-c++, heap-memory

I am working on Visual Studio and I see that in our code(huge code base, with complex business use cases) that in a flow we are not freeing memory of a pointer that comes to the function. I was expecting that the memory would be freed there.

Is there a way I can figure out if that memory address(I know the address since it came to the function) has been freed or still owner by the process?

I tried "HeapMemView" and "RamMap". To test those I just created a pointer and assigned memory and tried viewing that using those viewers. The code I wrote was,

```
char *a=new char[1000];
char str[1000];
sprintf(str,"Address : %p",a);
MessageBox(0, str, "MessageBox", MB_OK);
```

and I try to see the address value printed using the tools above but I am not able to see the addresses.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external tool such as Purify in order to analyze your memory leaks.
The other technique under Visual Studio would be to use the CRT Debugging techniques in order to trace memory allocation/deallocation.

Please have a look on below link:
[CRT Debugging techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh712wwf.aspx)